Django con Docker - WARNINGS: ?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory '/var/www/static/' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist
Al ejecutar el docker de un proyecto Django con el comando
docker run -p 0000:8000 proyectoejemplo

me sale el siguiente error:
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory '/var/www/static/' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

Pero en realidad en settings.py sí está definido:
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

STATICFILES_DIRS_ = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    "/var/www/static/",
]

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10.12
WORKDIR /proyectoejemplo
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
#CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]

¿Por qué no reconoce staticfiles_dirs?
Además la teminal de Visual Studio Code se queda ejecutada y no lo puedo detener. Debo cerrar la ventana de terminal, abrir uno nuevo, buscar el ID del docker, hacer stop, y crear otro mediante "docker build ." y de nuevo probar eun "docker run".
